# size calculation of selected rows in MYSQL data base

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate the exact size occupied by the selected rows in a table.
Table has different column data types like int, varchar, date...

example:

> SNO(INT) ,  NAME(VARCHAR) ,  DATE(DATE)
>
> 1    ,       ABC      ,  20-01-2017
>
> 2     ,      BCD       ,     11-01-2017

My aim is to calculate the size occupied totally by the two rows of data with respective to their actual data type storage.

like sum(size(SNO)+size(NAME)+size(DATE))

Can anyone help me to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get mysql row size in GB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715487/how-to-get-mysql-row-size-in-gb)

Answer (score 0):

it calculate sum of all column size datatype

```
SELECT sum(cast(substring_index(COLUMN_TYPE,'(',-1) as signed)) as totalsum,
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'mytable';
```

here replace with 'mytable' to your table name

Comment: r u satisfied with this query or not? please leave comment instead of answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your update denny.

that is the sum of column size.May be mistake from my side.I don't want column size.I want data size.

> SNO(INT) , NAME(VARCHAR) , DATE(DATE)
>
> 1 , ABC , 20-01-2017
>
> 2 , BCD , 11-01-2017

like `sum( size(1)+size(ABC)+size(20-01-2017))`.

size occupied by the data in the memory.

Thanks

Comment: this is not an answer, this should be a comment on denny's answer or an edit to the question.